# HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available jersey tomcat

Tags: rest, jersey, tomcat8

I am having trouble to launch my testing app on the tomcat8 server. When i enter the    `http://localhost:8080/loginService/rest/auth`, the error message is "HTTP Status 404 - 
type Status report. message: description The requested resource is not available."
And the starting page `http://localhost:8080/` works fine.
I put all the jar files(jersey-client, jersey-common, jersey-container-servlet,jersey-container-servlet-core, jersey-server, javax.ws.rs-api-2.0 ....) under the WEB-INF/lib. And loginService is deployed by the server.

the web.xml file under WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
     version="2.5">
    <display-name>loginService</display-name>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>loginTest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

my testing app:

```
package loginTest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
 @Path("/auth")
 public class Authenticate {
// This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String test() {
          return "succes";
      }
}
```

Here are the part of the console msg which seems like a problem:

```
七月 10, 2014 3:06:20 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
严重: Exception starting Context with name [/loginService]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/loginService]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3780)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1369)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1369)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Function
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinder.<clinit>(ServiceFinder.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ServletContainerProviderFactory.getAllServletContainerProviders(ServletContainerProviderFactory.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Function
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    ... 13 more

七月 10, 2014 3:06:20 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
信息: Reloading Context with name [/loginService] is completed
```

And I am using tomcat8 and jersey2.10.1.

I just changed my web.xml file to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee      
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="2.5">
  <display-name>loginService</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>loginTest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Make sure you have kept the Jersey Jar files in WEB-INF> lib folder?

Comment: First thing I noticed:

"com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer" Is Jersey 1.X not Jersey 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your application is missing some of the required libraries or (Since you already have the jercy-common.jar) there is an incompatibility in the libraries already in the classpath.

Therefore I would like to point out a perfectly working(Tested with Tomcat 8) sample in the below link.

[Jersey-HelloWorld-Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-hello-world-example/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I just solved it by deleting all web.xml files (inside "target" folder and "main" folder). Then right click on the project in Project Explorer and java EE tools -> Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub. After that just right click again on the project -> run as -> Maven build... Then in "Goals" field write: "clean install" (whithout quotes). Click on Apply, click on Run. Then go to your Tomcat manager, undeploy the old .war file and deploy it again. Then just run it! It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html#TomcatDebug , there are many reasons for this kind of problem to occur. In addition, I had been through this problem before. I solved it through the following way. Take a look at the web.xml heading in tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml. And make sure your your web.xml looks like that. Specially try to compare the versions. For instance:
Mine was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 ........
..........
</web-app>
```

The tomcat version that you install can be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
 ........
..........
</web-app>
```

If you look at both they have version difference and metadata attribute difference. So header of both your web.xml and tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml must be identical. By changing version number within the header of my web.xml into 4 solved my problem. Whatever version you have, make sure it is identical with the ROOT's web.xml version. Hope it helps